# How to Add multiple queries in bcp command sql server

Tags: sql-server

i have the following query passed in bcp command and the command is not executing due to multiple query

```
bcp  " SET NOCOUNT ON;IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[primaryKeys]') AND type in (N'U'))     SELECT primary_key_name,[schema_name],table_name,column_name,successfully_removed ,successfully_readded,alter_command_drop ,alter_command_add FROM primaryKeys"  c:\Testing.xls -c -STest -dMydb -Usa -PPassword1
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the `queryout` option:

```
bcp  "SET NOCOUNT ON;IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[primaryKeys]') AND type in (N'U'))     SELECT primary_key_name,[schema_name],table_name,column_name,successfully_removed ,successfully_readded,alter_command_drop ,alter_command_add FROM primaryKeys" quryout c:\Testing.xls -c -STest -dMydb -Usa -PPassword
```